# Can't build flutter ios with Firebase analytics running flutter build ios on codemagic.io cloud CI/CD

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase-analytics, codemagic

I have added `GoogleService-Info.plist` to `ios\Runner` using **XCode**.

I created this **Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Runner' do
  #use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

**pubspec.yaml** has

```
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
```

Still get this error building on https://codemagic.io/

```
Xcode's output:
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'firebase_analytics' not found
    @import firebase_analytics;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Try removing `use_frameworks!` from `ios/Podfile`, and see if that works

Comment: it's already #d thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK the answer from @Ashok was a good start.  After you delete the old Podfile and other stuff, you run `pod install` and a new `Podfile` is created.  You need to add

```
platform :ios, '9.0' #uncomment this
```

and

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 7.3.0'  #Highest pod version that works with flutter firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
...
```

Also in `AppFrameworkInfo.plist` add/edit

```
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>9.0</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the `DerivedData` from `Xcode` folder.

   Open `Runner.xcworkspace` inside the ios folder of your flutter project then select

   `File -> Workspace Settings ->` Click the grey arrow beside `DerivedData` path and delete the `DerivedData` inside the `Xcode` folder.
2. Delete `Podfile` inside ios folder of your flutter project.
3. Delete `Podfile.lock` inside ios folder of your flutter project.
4. Change the Deployment Target to `12.0`
5. Clean your ios build folder `(Command+Option+Shift+K)` Or from the `menu -> Product`, press Option on your keyboard and you'll see `Clean Build Folder`
6. Run your application and it should work

Comment: Thanks, but please note I am building this on codemagic.io CI/CD so its running a clean build each time (no DerivedData or Podfile.lock)

Comment: Also I thought 10.0 is enough for Firebase analytics no? Thanks again